# Why doesn't my python try-except bloc prevent for "Exception has occurred: ValueError"

Tags: python, exception, ip-address, try-except

I'm new here so sorry if I didn't know all formalities and habits.

I'm currently developping a PyQt application where the user can input an IP Address or a serial number (in the same field). Thus, I need to know if the input is an IP Address.

I used the *ip_address* function from the *ipaddress* :

```
from ipaddress import ip_address
def isIPValid(ipStr):
"""Checks if ipStr is a valid IP address"""
try:
    ip_address(ipStr)
    isValid = True
except ValueError:
    isValid = False
return isValid
```

The idea is that the ip is invalid if the ValueError exception is handled. It worked perfectly on the beginning of my project. However I really don't know what happened because now I get the error text that kills my application :

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
'2001-0257-3045' does not appear to be an IPv4 or IPv6 address
```

So basically the try/except bloc doesn't seem to work anymore.
I don't remember doing changes in this function.
The exception occurred inside the try/except bloc.

Any ideas?

I run my program from the "Python File" debug configuration of Visual Studio Code

Comment: Are you sure you're not running in a debugger configured to break on all exceptions?

Comment: Add the error message as text in the question, not as a link. A question should be self-contained as much as possible.

Comment: ...although in this case, keeping the link along with the text gives a hint that you are running in a debugger. So, how are you running this code? Does it work differently if you run it from the command line or without debugging?

Comment: @AKX Not really, I use the "Python File" debug configuration from Visual Studio Code.
I just tried to launch my main.py of the windows powershell and it worked perfectly.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Run the application from a debugger configured to break on all exceptions

My example works well on Windows PowerShell